# Adding a payload to createAction function using reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

How do i add a payload to createAction from the now function?

convert from this:

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/actions-type"
import { createAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
export function addArticle(payload) {
  return { type: ADD_ARTICLE, payload }
};
```

convert to this:

```
export const addArticle = createAction(ADD_ARTICLE, ????)
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of `createAction` is a function which takes the arguments of your action creator and maps them to an object with the `payload` property.  Since your action creator takes the whole `payload` as an argument, it's this:

```
export const addArticle = createAction(ADD_ARTICLE, payload => ({payload}));
```

Answer (score 2):

For TypeScript, adding a generic type to createAction hints the resulting action creator takes a payload of type `PayloadType`:

```
export const addArticle = createAction<PayloadType>(ADD_ARTICLE)
```

then for `payload: PayloadType`, you can

```
dispatch(addArticle(payload))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything. The result of `createAction` is an action creator function that accepts one argument and puts it on `payload`.

So `export const addArticle = createAction(ADD_ARTICLE)` does exactly what you want.